# Mysql query successful, but not updating

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

I'm working on an RPG-type battle system for a friend and have run into frustrating issues with a mysql query. Also, no lectures on the semantics of mysql_ functions, please.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `user_pets` SET `curhp` = `hitpoints`, `curmp` = `misticpower`, `pet_status` = '0' WHERE `id` = '" .$arrayPet['id']. "'";
if ( mysql_query($sql) {
    echo "Success";
}
```

This comes back as success every time in the application. However, nothing is actually happening in the database. I've echo'd the query itself and ran it in phpmyadmin and the "healing" is completed properly. However, WHATEVER is actually happening when this query executes, it is not what is desired.

Any recommendations for troubleshooting, or can you see anything wrong with the query itself?

$arrayPet['id'] is taken from the `user_pets` table and is a valid ID.

Comment: [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) should tell you if a row was actually affected by your query.

Comment: The use of `mysql_*` functions are discouraged. You should use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: @Mike that is not helpful towards finding a solution to my question, and I even requested that peoeple NOT bring that up.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I added that to the script immediately following the query and it comes back saying one row was affected, but the expected changes did not occur. As a comment, I posted below an example of what SHOULD be happening.

Comment: Did you change your ` around values to `'` as @osg suggested?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I recommend is not wrapping `$arrayPet['id']` in single quotes... I'm assuming it's an integer.

Second is if the function mysql_query() returns successfully, it doesn't necessarily mean anything got updated.  It just means the query executed successfully on the server.  Your query looks like all it does is set some strings and set pet_status to 0.  Please provide:

1. An actual sample of a row of the data from user_pets
2. What you expect the row to look like after this query runs

Comment: As an example: after a battle, the user does not have his maximum health. Say his health is 25 out of 50, and misticpower is 15 of 30. This query is supposed to return those values to the max possible value (hitpoints and misticpower in the database). However, it does neither.

Comment: @Eric  is `hitpoints` is a variable  you replace with a number?  If not it looks like your trying to update strings into what are integer columns (assuming curhp, curmp are integers).  This will probably fail to update.

Comment: hitpoints is a field in the table, an integer that does not change. curhp is an integer field that stores how much HP they currently have(after being attacked, etc). I'm telling it to set curhp to hitpoints (a full heal). I've tried specifying the values to set curhp to instead of using the column names, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_pets SET curhp = 'hitpoints', curmp = 'misticpower', pet_status = '0' WHERE id = '" .$arrayPet['id']. "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
echo "Success";
```

}

More importantly, check your $arrayPet['id']: does it return an integer or string value? If it's an integer type, then don't put it inside single quote. Just do something like this:

```
... WHERE id = $arrayPet['id']";
```

Comment: Trying that, it says that the query was successful. I even added mysql_affected_rows() after, and it returns saying it did affect a row. Though, no change is made in the database on the requested row. As an example: after a battle, the user does not have his maximum health. Say his health is 25 out of 50, and misticpower is 15 of 30. This query is supposed to return those values to the max possible value (hitpoints and misticpower in the database). However, it does neither.

Comment: Are you sure it's querying the same database?

Comment: Positive. There are two other mysql_query() on either side of this one and both are affecting the correct database.